# How many races go from first contact to Federation member on screen?

Tags: star-trek

There have been many instances of 'first contact' in Star Trek.

I'm interested in knowing how many of those civilisations have gone on to join the Federation.

Obviously all the races in the Federation had a first contact at one point or another, so you could just give the answer "all of them", but I'm specifically thinking of those whose first contact was shown in an episode or film, and then shown later as being full Federation members.

[edit]

To clarify, in response to the comments:

What I'm really looking is for races who were contacted **by the Federation** and then joined it as members.

So that excludes Humans, Vulcans, et al, who were founding members and also any other species who already had contact prior to the Federation being formed, even if they didn't actually join it from the beginning.

As a related question, I'm also interested in how long it would typically take between first contact with the Federation and gaining membership to it, though I guess I may need to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Are we counting all of the races encountered in Star Trek: Enterprise  / Star Trek First Contact (e.g. Vulcan, Andorians, etc) and episodes set far into the future that show races such as the Klingons being part of the Federation?

Comment: **Vulcan -** Star Trek: First Contact. **Risa -** Star Trek: Enterprise - Two Days and Two Nights, **Andoria -** Star Trek: Enterprise - The Andorian Incident, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, Vulcan in the First Contact film was the obvious one. For some reason I'd completely blanked ST:E out of my mind, but yes I'll accept Risa and Andoria. Are there any others (and are there any that weren't in TS:E?)

Comment: Do the species in "Live Fast and Prosper" count?

Comment: Don't forget __human__ - we see their first contact in First Contact, too.

Comment: Let's not forget that the Federation didn't exist at the time of human/Vuclan First Contact; "The Federation was founded in San Francisco, Earth in 2161. (TNG: "The Outcast"; ENT: "Zero Hour", "These Are the Voyages...") The seeds of the Federation were planted during the Babel Crisis of 2154, during which a temporary alliance was formed to search for a Romulan drone ship preying on local vessels. It was this that first brought together the species that founded the Federation: Humans, Vulcans, Andorians, and Tellarites" ( from http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets )

Comment: Does the species' Federation membership have to be cannon? Because according to various novels, the Horta species became a Federation member following first contact in TOS: The Devil in the Dark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very many. Memory Alpha has a list of First Contact incidents:
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_contacts

Many First Contact incidents are with non-corporeal beings, artificial life forms, or space lifeforms who never become members of the Federation, and are never seen again after one episode.

Others are with primitive species, or even extinct species.

None become Federation members.

From this list, the Vulcans, Andorians, Tellarites were the only ones we saw *literally* become Federation members.

First Contact with the Risians happened on screen in Enterprise, but sometime between Enterprise and TNG the Risians became members of the Federation.

We can assume that First Contact between the Federation and the Bajorans happened sometime before TNG, and almost see them become a member of the Federation.

We also know lots of species, like the Rigelians were encountered between the Star Trek movie *First Contact* and Enterprise, and later became Federation members, but we don't see either First Contact with them, or their induction into the Federation.

Betazoids, Trill, Ktaris, Grazerites, Bolians, etc were all Federation members, but we never saw First Contact, nor their induction into the Federation.

Comment: I'm reading the question's requirements as 1) first contact is made by the Federation, and we see it on screen and 2) we see them on screen at a later time, as Federation members. (1) disqualifies Vulcans, Andorians, Tellarites, Bajorans... everybody but the Risians (if the Federation was formed by that time). So it looks to me like your answer is either just the RIsians, or nobody.

Comment: Thank you. I think this answers the question. Seems like a missed opportunity to me -- it could have made a great story arc (or even a movie) in TNG to show a new member being inducted into the Federation.

Comment: Yup, the closest is the Bajorans I think, but we missed out on first contact. With the Risians we got first contact, but missed their joining.

Comment: Also @DCShannon, when I wrote the answer originally the details ended with: "Obviously all the races in the Federation had a first contact at one point or another, so you could just give the answer "all of them", but I'm specifically thinking of those whose first contact was shown in an episode or film, and then shown later as being full Federation members." So I assumed Federation members discovered before the Federation existed, who then became members were valid.

Comment: According to the edit logs, since Mar 29th it has said "races who were contacted by the Federation", with the last three words in bold. And also that that excludes "any other species who already had contact prior to the Federation being formed". Your answer came in more than a month after that.

Comment: Yeah that was there. The bit explaining that Vulcans et. al., don't count is newer I think.